# Changed label text on form, designer shows new text, running program shows old text

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, designer

I change the text property of labels on a windows form.  The form displays the correct new labels when displayed in the VS 2010 forms designer.  I also change the color of the font.

When I run the program, the window displays the old text values instead of the new text values.  The form displays the new font color on the labels.

There seems to be no occurrences of the old text value in the source code.  Where is the old text value still hiding?

I clean the solution and rebuild it, but nothing changes.

Comment: Please post your code too.

Comment: Try deleting your `bin` folder entirely. Also try finding all references to the label: perhaps something is loading text from a resource file or something like that.

Comment: You can also check the `.Text` and `.BackColor` properties in your `<form name>.Designer.cs` file.

Comment: Thank you both for the suggestions.  This is an old vb.net project.  The generated designer code seems to be embedded in the Form1.vb code, rather than in a separate partial class file.  The Text property is set to the new value.  I cannot determine where the old text value even exists. I did delete the bin and obj folders.I did lookup all references to the label name and found nothing amiss

Comment: Is there some hidden resource file or registry store where the old text values are retained?  The program appears to set the new values into the .text properties.

Comment: Are the values being read in from an `app.config` somewhere?

Comment: The values are hard-coded into the designer and never changed by the application.  At least I cannot find where they are being changed....

Answer (score 0):

A colleague observed that this is an artifact of converting projects from VS2005 to vs2008 to VS2010 and suggested a "brute force" corrective measure.

It actually worked.

1) Create a new blank form in the project.

2) In the original form, using the forms designer "Edit" menu, use the "select all" and "copy" actions.  This copies all forms objects into the clipboard.

3) Paste the clipboard into the blank form.

4) Copy (most of) the program code from the old form into the new form, excluding anything generated by the forms designer.

5) Delete the old form from the project.  Make changes as necessary to use the new form

Not very elegant, but good for meeting a deadline.

Thank you J.H!

Answer (score 0):

Epilog:

"Brian" and "Blogbeard" both had the right direction in suggesting a hidden resource file.

Early in the execution of the code lay a method call to an obscure subsystem that no one knew anything about.  That subsystem turned out to be a defunct language translation module which was supposed to translate all of the labels in a form from a native language to a target language.

It was configured to keep the original labels and their translations in a file outside the scope of the IDE.  Changes in the form itself were completely ignored if the translator found the label name in its file.

Moving the form contents to another package effectively disabled the translator.

The elegant solution turned out to a three-line change that removed the method call to the translator. (it was no longer required in the application)